# How to solve "AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__name__'"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

'''import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'''

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more? have you installed matplotlib

Comment: Yes, I already installed Matplotlib.